# How to export the root certificate issued by Microsoft Certificate Server

Tags: java, active-directory, certificate

I want to update Active Directory password from Java application, but it needs to import trusted Root Certificate on a Java client machine. How to export the root certificate issued by Microsoft Certificate Server?

Comment: What a format of certificate?

Comment: maybe it is  a file!

Comment: May be `keytool.exe` will help you. It is located in `bin\` directory of your jre root path. If you need, I can show example.

Comment: please show me your example!

Answer (score 1):

To add certificate, you can use `keytool.exe`, that located in `bin` folder of you JRE root. For example JRE root folder is `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre`. Then command line to **import** will be:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -keystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -importcert -file "c:\temp\startssl.crt" -alias startssl
```

`-keystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\security\cacerts"` means the default path to keystore on your computer.

`-storepass changeit` means password for store. By default is `changeit`.

`-importcert` means you would like to import new certificate.

`-file "c:\temp\startssl.crt"` the path to your certificate file.

`-alias startssl` means that `startssl` will the name of certificate in store. You can choose any unique name.

---

To **export** certificate from store:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -keystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -exportcert -rfc -file "c:\temp\startssl_exp.crt" -alias root
```

`-exportcert` means, you would like to export certificate.

`-alias root` the name of certificate. Root certificate has name `root` by  default

`-file "c:\temp\startssl_exp.crt"`, the file name, where you want to save certificate.

`-rfc` means, that certificate will be outputted in printable RFC format.

---

To **delete** already imported certificate, you can use next command:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0\bin\keytool.exe" -keystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -delete -alias startssl
```

`-delete` means you would like delete certificate.

`-alias startssl` the name of certificate, you would like to delete.

*This example for Windows, but Linux will be working same way. Full documentation [you can find here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html). Hope, this will be helpful.*

Comment: thank you in advance, my question is how to export certificate not import it!

Comment: @VinoDang, I updated answer for export. By the way, there is a lot of options and setting in documentation. For example, there is command `-list` that can show you the list of all certificates in the storage, and many other. You can find it all by the link I have pointed at the end of response.

Comment: Note, that you'll need run `cmd.exe` with administrator access level

Answer (score 1):

Do the following on the server machine:

- start the server-manager
- in the upper right corner of the server-manager click on tools - certificate authority
- click on "issued certificates"
- doubleclick the AD certificate, click on details and then "copy to file"
- click next, choose "base64 (.CER)" and choose a filename

**See also:**

- [Microsoft Technet - LDAP over SSL (LDAPS) Certificate](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2980.ldap-over-ssl-ldaps-certificate.aspx#Exporting_and_Importing_the_LDAPS_Certificate)